# Render file generated by html webpack plugin whithin router

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, koa, html-webpack-plugin

how are you going? I'm facing an annoying problem. I'm not being able to find `index.html` generated by `html-webpack-plugin` in order to render it. I can access it on `localhost:8080/index.html`, but I don't know how could I render it on my routes with handlebars.

What I wanna do: Find my view after injection and render it with koa-views and handlebars.

Entire code: https://github.com/vini175pa/koa-redux-starterkit

Routes: [first link]/blob/master/server/routes/index.js

Webpack.config.js https://github.com/vini175pa/koa-redux-starterkit/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can read this.

https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/145

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var compiler = webpack(require('./webpack.config.js'));

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: '/'
}));

app.use('*', function (req, res, next) {
  var filename = path.join(compiler.outputPath,'index.html');
  compiler.outputFileSystem.readFile(filename, function(err, result){
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.set('content-type','text/html');
    res.send(result);
    res.end();
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```